# Displaying data on different card view

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, jstl

I am displaying weather data for each city on a card on button click

**JSP page**

```
 <c:forEach var="list" items="${listHist}">
            <div class="w3-container">
             <ul class="w3-ul w3-card-4">
             <li class="w3-bar">
             <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-white w3-xlarge w3-right">×</span>
          <img src="resources/assets/images/a1.png" class="w3-bar-item w3-circle w3-hide-small" style="width:85px">
           <div class="w3-bar-item">
            <span><font size="6">Name : ${list.name}</font></span><br>
            <span>
            <ul><li class="card-text">Ticket Number : ${list.ticketNo}
                        <li class="card-text">From : ${list.fromCity}
                        <li class="card-text">To : ${list.toCity}
                        <li class="card-text">Date : ${list.travelDate}
                        <li class="card-text">Travel Class : ${list.travelClass}
                        <li  class="card-text">Gender : ${list.gender}
                        <li  class="card-text">Passenger type : ${list.ptype}
                        <li  class="card-text">Price : ${list.price}
                            <p id="weatherdata"></p>    
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                        </span>
                <font color="white"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="currWeather(&quot;${list.toCity}&quot;);myFunction();" style="margin-left: 0px ">Weather</button></font>
            </div>
        </div>
        </c:forEach>
```

**My script:** *I have used jquery weather script where yahoo api has been used to fetch weather data for that city*

```
function currWeather(city){

     var city =city;
      $(document).ready(function() {

               $.simpleWeather({
                 location: city+', IN',
                 woeid: '',
                 unit: 'c',
                 success: function(weather) {                       
                         $("p").slideToggle();
                        /*  $("div") */
                           document.getElementById("weatherdata").innerHTML=weather.code+" "+weather.temp+ " "+weather.units.temp+" "+weather.currently;
                 },
                 error: function(error) {
                     document.getElementById("weatherdata").innerHTML=error;
                 }
               });
             });

  }
```

**Problem:** The data from the function is always displayed on the first card, even if the button on other cards are pressed. I want to display the weather data individually on each card after clicking on the button.

Comment: You need to have a unique ID for "weatherdata" so that only that one is used to append the data. Repeated controls with the same id will always return only the first control when getElementById is used.

Comment: yes but the problem is we are getting list values from spring mvc controller and we can't give id for each item in the item list please check my for:each loop

Comment: have you tried  `<p id="weatherdata_#{loop.count}"></p> ` or even `<p id="weatherdata_${list.name}"></p>`

Comment: @Yasir some people like are so genius OMG! please post an answer I will verify your answer since it completely worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using an index or a name `<p id="weatherdata_#{loop.count}"></p>` or even `<p id="weatherdata_${list.name}"></p>`

Use that unique id in the script

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting my question and your answer since you have solved my problem....

Answer (score 0):

**JSP Page:**

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${listHist}">
                <div class="w3-container">
                 <ul class="w3-ul w3-card-4">
                 <li class="w3-bar">
                 <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-white w3-xlarge w3-right">×</span>
              <img src="resources/assets/images/a1.png" class="w3-bar-item w3-circle w3-hide-small" style="width:85px">
               <div class="w3-bar-item">
                <span><font size="6">Name : ${list.name}</font></span><br>
                <span>
                <ul><li class="card-text">Ticket Number : ${list.ticketNo}
                            <li class="card-text">From : ${list.fromCity}
                            <li class="card-text">To : ${list.toCity}
                            <li class="card-text">Date : ${list.travelDate}
                            <li class="card-text">Travel Class : ${list.travelClass}
                            <li  class="card-text">Gender : ${list.gender}
                            <li  class="card-text">Passenger type : ${list.ptype}
                            <li  class="card-text">Price : ${list.price}
                                <p id="weatherdata_${list.ticketNo}"></p>    
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                            </span>

                    <font color="white"><button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" onclick="currWeather(&quot;${list.toCity}&quot;,${list.ticketNo});" style="margin-left: 0px ">Weather</button></font>
                </div>
            </div>
            </c:forEach>
```

**My Script:**

```
function currWeather(city,ticketNo){
    console.log(ticketNo);
    console.log(city);
    var city =city;
     $(document).ready(function() {

              $.simpleWeather({
                location: city+', IN',
                woeid: '',
                unit: 'c',
                success: function(weather) {                       
                        $("#weatherdata_"+ticketNo).slideToggle();
                       /*  $("div") */
                          document.getElementById("weatherdata_"+ticketNo).innerHTML=weather.code+" "+weather.temp+ " "+weather.units.temp+" "+weather.currently;
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    document.getElementById("weatherdata_"+ticketNo).innerHTML=error;
                }
              });
            });

 }
```